# JMeter - JSONObject not found in namespace error through CLI only

Tags: jmeter, command-line-interface

I am experiencing an error using a Java/Beanshell 2.0b6 when running a script through the CLI on a Macbook, which does not occur when running through the GUI;

```
2023-12-04 16:52:47,858 ERROR o.a.j.m.JSR223PreProcessor: Problem in JSR223 script, JSR223 PreProcessor - Create tokenPayload
javax.script.ScriptException: Sourced file: inline evaluation of: ``import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.CookieManager;   import org.apach . . . '' : Typed variable declaration : Class: JSONObject not found in namespace : at Line: 10 : in file: inline evaluation of: ``import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.CookieManager;   import org.apach . . . '' : JSONObject 
 in inline evaluation of: ``import org.apache.jmeter.protocol.http.control.CookieManager;   import org.apach . . . '' at line number 10
    at bsh.engine.BshScriptEngine.evalSource(BshScriptEngine.java:93) ~[bsh-2.0b6.jar:2.0b6 2016-02-05 05:16:19]
    at bsh.engine.BshScriptEngine.eval(BshScriptEngine.java:46) ~[bsh-2.0b6.jar:2.0b6 2016-02-05 05:16:19]
    at javax.script.AbstractScriptEngine.eval(AbstractScriptEngine.java:231) ~[java.scripting:?]
    at org.apache.jmeter.util.JSR223TestElement.processFileOrScript(JSR223TestElement.java:219) ~[ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.2]
    at org.apache.jmeter.modifiers.JSR223PreProcessor.process(JSR223PreProcessor.java:45) [ApacheJMeter_components.jar:5.4.2]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.runPreProcessors(JMeterThread.java:965) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.2]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.executeSamplePackage(JMeterThread.java:549) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.2]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.processSampler(JMeterThread.java:489) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.2]
    at org.apache.jmeter.threads.JMeterThread.run(JMeterThread.java:256) [ApacheJMeter_core.jar:5.4.2]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:1589) [?:?]
```

The org.json .jar file exists in /lib and the JMETER_HOME classpath seems to be correctly set to the installation directory. Could anyone please advise what may be the issue and why the jar cannot be found at runtime?

(Note - Appreciate I should be using a JSR223 / Groovy but there is a bit of a disconnect between the Java version (19) and JMeter version (5.4.2) stopping me from doing this for the code in question)

Would just like to understand why there is a disconnect between the GUI and the CLI

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. There should not be "disconnect", most probably you're running different JMeter versions for "CLI" and "GUI" modes, compare [jmeter.log files](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/get-started.html#logging) for both and you should see the full path to JMeter binaries, [Classpath](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/paths.html), etc.
2. If you want to use Groovy you could [update Groovy libraries](https://groovy.apache.org/download.html) in "lib" folder of your JMeter installation or downgrade to [Java 17](https://openjdk.org/projects/jdk/17/).
3. [It's recommended to always use the latest version of JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jmeter-memory-profiling#use-up-to-date-software) so consider upgrading to [JMeter 5.6.2](https://lists.apache.org/thread/49dnwvyozy535ogwqvdvbkwkgk0xkrrl) or whatever is the latest stable version which is available at [JMeter Downloads](https://jmeter.apache.org/download_jmeter.cgi) page.

Comment: You're a genius, thank you! You're right - there were two installations of JMeter (one was in a hidden folder on the Mac). Also managed to update the groovy libraries to 4.0, so the script that was failing to compile using Java 19 now compiles successfully. Thanks again